# Force one argument to be greater than another in Idris

Tags: idris

I am trying to write a function `mSmallest` that takes two natural numbers, `n` and `m` as inputs and produces a vector. The output vector contains the `m` smallest members of the finite set with `n` members.

For example `mSmallest 5 3` is supposed to produce `[FS (FS Z), FS Z, Z]` which is a `Vect 3 (Fin 5)`

I would like to restrict the input argument `m` to be less than `n`. I tried something like this:

```
mSmallest : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> {auto p : n > m = True} -> Vect m (Fin n)
mSmallest Z Z = ?c_3                                                                   
mSmallest Z (S k) = ?c_5                                                               
mSmallest (S k) m = ?c_2
```

The second case should not be possible because of the input `p`.  How do I make it so that the `Z (S k)` case is eliminated?

Also, is there a better way of defining the `mSmallest` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think `n > m = True` is constructive enough; if you use the `GT` proposition instead, you can eliminate the first two branches since there's no way to pattern-match on `p` in that case:

```
-- Note that mSmallest is accepted as total with just this one case!
total mSmallest : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> {auto p : n `GT` m} -> Vect m (Fin n)
mSmallest (S k) m {p = LTESucc p} = replicate m FZ
```

(this one uses a dummy implementation of `mSmallest` for the interesting case since that should be orthogonal to the original question).

Comment: Thanks! I don't really understand the `{p = LTESucc p}` part.  I didn't believe this would be necessary, and when I removed it, the code still compiled.  What is the purpose of it?

Comment: It might not be... It was left there as I was case-splitting on the `p` argument to ensure the other two cases are absurd. Although, you might need it for recursive calls in the real implementation of `mSmallest`.

Comment: I think `m > n = True` actually *should* be good enough, although the wild west flavor of Idris classes will probably make this tricky to express (i.e., you probably need to explicitly invoke the canonical `Ord` instance). You'll then end up doing a case by case proof that digs into the implementation of `compare` for `Nat` to prove that, modulo typeclass nonsense, `n > m = True -> GT n m`. Assuming this is possible, it will probably something ugly with `the` and `%instance` and `@` and curly braces.